# SharePoint 2010 pre-configured (non-HA) VM image in Azure

Tags: azure

Have anyone tried to create a SharePoint 2010 preconfigured dev VM in Azure lately? Can't seem to find the SP2010 image from the gallery anymore. Or is there a quick and easy way to have a boilerplate SP2010 development machine in Azure? All I found right now is a dated document from Microsoft about installing SP2010 on Azure VM and also the AutoSPInstaller option. I can do the manual/scripted deployment all fine but I'm hoping someone knows of a better/faster option close to having a boilerplate image like the one Azure offered before?